# How to serialize an irregular pandas hourly timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas

**The question:**

How can I transform a pandas series with the values `['2020-11-11 00:00:00', ..., '2020-11-13 12:00:00']` to the number of hours from some epoch?

**The details with sample code:**

I've got a dataframe such as this:

```
     date_day            date_hour  value date_day_timestamp
0  2020-11-11  2020-11-11 00:00:00      1         2020-11-11
1  2020-11-12  2020-11-11 12:00:00      2         2020-11-12
2  2020-11-14  2020-11-12 00:00:00      4         2020-11-14
3  2020-11-15  2020-11-12 12:00:00      2         2020-11-15
4  2020-11-21  2020-11-13 00:00:00      3         2020-11-21
5  2020-11-22  2020-11-13 12:00:00      2         2020-11-22
```

The column `date_day_timestamp` is a timestamp series where the first observation is `Timestamp('2020-11-11 00:00:00')` of type `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` and calculated from the column `date_day` (where the observationis are of type `str`) using `df['date_day_serial'] = [(d-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days for d in df['date_day_timestamp']]`.

This gives me a pandas  series of type `inumpy.int64nt` with the values `[18577, 18578, 18580, 18581, 18587, 18588]` which is a serialized representaion of the dates starting from `1970-01-01`

How can I get a similar column that is based on the number of ***hours*** from `1970-01-01`, or some other epoch? In the data sample, I've got two observations per day at `00:00:00` and `12:00:00`, but I'd like this to work for other times of day, and even with irregular number of hours per day.

I've naively replacing `days` wiht `hours` in `df['date_day_serial'] = [(d-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).hours for d in df['date_day_timestamp']]`, but this raises an `AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'hours'`. And if we calculate one single timedelta like `timedelta = df['date_day_timestamp'].iloc[1]-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)`, we can see that `dir(timedelta)` only returns `Timedelta('18578 days 00:00:00')`. No number of hours ready for the grabbing there...

So, how can I calculate this using another approach? Is there something I could just replace `(d-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).hours` with in the setup below to get what I want?

**This is my latest attempt:**

```
df['date_hour_serial'] = [(d-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).hours for d in df['date_hour_timestamp']]
```

**Complete code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df=pd.DataFrame({'date_day': {0: '2020-11-11',
                      1: '2020-11-12',
                      2: '2020-11-14',
                      3: '2020-11-15',
                      4: '2020-11-21',
                      5: '2020-11-22'},
                 'date_hour': {0: '2020-11-11 00:00:00',
                      1: '2020-11-11 12:00:00',
                      2: '2020-11-12 00:00:00',
                      3: '2020-11-12 12:00:00',
                      4: '2020-11-13 00:00:00',
                      5: '2020-11-13 12:00:00'},
                     'value': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 2,}})

df['date_day_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_day'])
df['date_day_serial'] = [(d-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days for d in df['date_day_timestamp']]

df['date_hour_timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_hour'])
timedelta = df['date_day_timestamp'].iloc[1]-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)

df

# the next line raises an error
#df['date_hour_serial'] = [(d-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).hours for d in df['date_hour_timestamp']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest is convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) or to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and then count another values by multiply or divide constant like `24`, `60`, `3600`, because `.hours` or `.minutes` is not implemented for timedeltas:

```
df['date_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_hour'])

s = df['date_hour'].sub(pd.Timestamp('1971-01-01'))
#counts only days without hours
df['date_hour_serial1'] = s.dt.days.mul(24)
#count days with hours
df['date_hour_serial2'] = s.dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
print (df)
     date_day           date_hour  value  date_hour_serial1  date_hour_serial2
0  2020-11-11 2020-11-11 00:00:00      1             437088           437088.0
1  2020-11-12 2020-11-11 12:00:00      2             437088           437100.0
2  2020-11-14 2020-11-12 00:00:00      4             437112           437112.0
3  2020-11-15 2020-11-12 12:00:00      2             437112           437124.0
4  2020-11-21 2020-11-13 00:00:00      3             437136           437136.0
5  2020-11-22 2020-11-13 12:00:00      2             437136           437148.0
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this! But the difference between `437112` and `431088` is 24, and the difference between the firts two `date_hour` observations is `12 hours`. Maybe I've phrased the difference a bit poorly. I'll take a look again right now.

Comment: @vestland - then is necessary convert to seconds

Comment: @vestland - I test with seconds and get same output

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. I'm aiming to use values like `2020-11-11 12:00:00` ***with*** the hours included in the timestamp. In other words: two obsevations per day. Or more, depending on how many hourly observations I've got per day.

Comment: @vestland - Then use `s.dt.total_seconds().div(3600)`, my problem was not parse `date_hour` column. Column `date_hour_serial1` is for compare days without hours